# Image not displaying from database with jQuery fadeToggle and button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cordova

I am using PhoneGap for client side and XAMPP for server side.

How the Live Search works: There is a search bar with a list of all items below it. The more characters are typed within the search field, the fewer items are displayed until there is one or none left based on the mySQL database. Each item has multiple data shown including an image.

**Question**: The button with the fadeToggle jQuery is not displaying any of my images from mySQL database. Without the button and fadeToggle jQuery, the images are displayed. But I need to hide the images initially, and only display them when requested by the user.

I have set my img property in the PHP file to style="display: none".

Is there a way to show those images individually rather than all at once?

**Why**: Loading every image within the database especially on mobile requires a long time especially when there is more than 100 entries.

**This seperate question have been solved in comments:**
I can't seem to be able to display any image from the path inserted into the database. It shows a broken image. When I right click on the broken image and open the image in a new tab, this error message appears `Cannot GET /artwork/image.jpg`

**PHP**: (server)

```
<?php
    //fetch.php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'qc_artwork') or die ("could not connect database");
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST["query"])){
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["query"]);
        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM artwork 
        WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%'
        OR barcode LIKE '%".$search."%'
        ";
    }
    else{
        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM artwork ORDER BY name ASC
        ";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $output .= '
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Path</th>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        ';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            <td><button>Show Image</button><img style="display: none" height="130" width="220" src="http://localhost/'.$row["path"].'"/></td>
            <td>'.$row["barcode"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["type"].'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
        echo $output;
    }
    else{
        echo 'Data Not Found';
    }
?>
```

**Index.html**: (client - PhoneGap)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ionic.css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                load_data();

                function load_data(query){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"localhost/fetch.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{query:query},
                        success:function(data){
                            $('#result').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }

                $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
                    var search = $(this).val();
                    if(search != ''){
                        load_data(search);
                    }
                    else{
                        load_data();
                    }
                });

                // Display Image with button
                $('button:first').click(function() {
                    $('img:first').fadeToggle('fast');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive" style="margin-bottom:80px;">
        <a href="index.html" class="button button-clear">Home</a>
        <h1 class="title">Search Database (JSON)</h1>
        </div><br/><br/>
        <div class="container">
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
                    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My SQL table consists of 5 columns:

1. id
2. name
3. path
4. barcode
5. type

Comment: does `/artwork/image.jpg` exist?

Comment: @rtfm yes it does

Comment: thats not what you say in the question

Comment: @rtfm what do you mean?

Comment: "When I right click on the broken image and open the image in a new tab, this error message appears Cannot GET /artwork/image.jpg"

Comment: Are all images are loaded locally with the app or you are fetching them from 152.228.1.48?

Comment: @rtfm I'll try to clarify. I can't display the actual image from the path in the database. All it shows is a broken image. When I right click on the image and select the option to open the image in a different tab, it displays this on the new tab  'Cannot GET /artwork/image.jpg'.

Comment: then surely "/artwork/image.jpg" does not exist

Comment: @ChrisChen as I am using PhoneGap to do this, I can fetch the data from db on my laptop browser where the images are stored with localhost but I would need the actual IP to access them from my phone.

Comment: @rtfm I would think it does, because typing `http://localhost/artwork/image.jpg` into my url on my browser gives me the image

Comment: `http://localhost` is not in your link

Comment: @rtfm the images are displayed properly if I directly access the `fetch.php` file on `http://localhost/fetch.php`. But the images only isn't displayed on `index.html` through PhoneGap

Comment: @rtfm Suprisingly, adding the `http://localhost/` or `http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/` solved the issue regarding the image not displaying. Do you know why is that so?

Comment: becuse browsers cant read minds how would if know that `/artwork/image.jpg` should be `http://localhost/artwork/image.jpg`

Comment: @rtfm I see. But why does accessing fetch.php directly works, even without the `http://localhost/`? thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: During your test on local machine, localhost redirect to 127.0.0.1 which is your own PC/Server. Once your app is live on the phone, you will need to direct it to a public domain or IP so they can find your server on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to dedicate a button to each image to display individually but I have manage to have a button to display or hide all images as a whole.

**jQuery**:

```
// Display image
$('#show_image').on('click', function() {
    $('img').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

**PHP**:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output .= '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["barcode"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["type"].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><img style="display: none; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%" src="http://localhost/'.$row["path"].'"/></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

and my `button`:

```
<button id="show_image">Image</button>
```